# results = results['results']['bindings'] Flask error

Tags: python, regex, flask, sparql, semantic-web

I try to obtain results bindings by this Sparql query.
Through this Sparql entry point: http://digitale.bncf.firenze.sbn.it/openrdf-workbench/repositories/NS_03_2014/query

I have the error: "TypeError: query() takes at least 2 arguments (1 given)

Thank you!!!

```
@app.route('/caricaArgomento/<type>', methods=['GET'])
def getArgomento(type):
    #sparql = SPARQLUpdateStore("http://digitale.bncf.firenze.sbn.it/openrdf-      workbench/repositories/NS_03_2014/query")
    sparql=SPARQLUpdateStore("http://digitale.bncf.firenze.sbn.it/openrdf-workbench/repositories/NS_03_2014/query")
    sparql.setQuery("""
    PREFIX dc:<http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/>
    PREFIX rdfs:<http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#>
    PREFIX nsogi:<http://prefix.cc/nsogi>
    PREFIX rdf:<http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#>
    PREFIX skos:<http://www.w3.org/2004/02/skos/core#>
    PREFIX dcterms:<http://purl.org/dc/terms/>
        SELECT ?risultato
        WHERE {
         ?item a skos:Concept .
         ?item skos:prefLabel ?risultato .
         filter regex(?risultato, """+type+""", "i")
        } ORDER BY  ?risultato
         """)

     #FILTER regex(str(?aConcept), "http://thes.bncf.firenze.sbn.it/", "i").}

    sparql.setReturnFormat(JSON)
    results = sparql.query().convert()
    results = results['results']['bindings']
    results = json.dumps(results)

return results
```

digitale.bncf.firenze.sbn.it
digitale.bncf.firenze.sbn.it

Answer (score 2):

Looking at the relevant [documentation](https://rdflib.readthedocs.org/en/latest/apidocs/rdflib.plugins.stores.html#rdflib.plugins.stores.sparqlstore.SPARQLUpdateStore) `sparql.query()...` requires a query argument.

```
sparql=SPARQLUpdateStore("http://digitale.bncf.firenze.sbn.it/openrdf-workbench/repositories/NS_03_2014/query")

sparql.setReturnFormat(JSON)

query = """
    PREFIX dc:<http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/>
    PREFIX rdfs:<http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#>
    PREFIX nsogi:<http://prefix.cc/nsogi>
    PREFIX rdf:<http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#>
    PREFIX skos:<http://www.w3.org/2004/02/skos/core#>
    PREFIX dcterms:<http://purl.org/dc/terms/>
    SELECT ?risultato
    WHERE {
     ?item a skos:Concept .
     ?item skos:prefLabel ?risultato .
     filter regex(?risultato, """+type+""", "i")
    } ORDER BY  ?risultato
"""

results = sparql.query(query).convert()
```

I can't work out what the purpose of `sparql.setQuery(...)` is, but clearly it's not what you want.

Edit:

Having looked at the source `setQuery(...)` is really for internal use (people writing subclasses, for example), and not for regular api users. It pulls out the query form and records the query text. `query(...)` calls it internally.

Comment: `SPARQLUpdateStore` wraps `SPARQLWrapper`, so probably a legacy method. Please, filean issue to github. Thanks.